# Asp.net cannot send value from a select to an http post in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a website where you can create shows and add them to a list.
Everything works when i create one, except there is one value that doesn't get sent to the post. That value is from a select.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idCategories, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select class="form-control" id="Categorie" name="Categorie">
            <option>--Choisir la categorie--</option>
            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Categories)
            {
                <option value="@item.idCategories">@item.Description</option>
            }
        </select>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idCategories, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

In this situation, all the values of each options are all normal values, from 1 to 5 for now. But when i press on the submit button to send an http post request, the value sent is always 0 and I can't seem to understand why. I send the information to this controller:
        `[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AjouterSpectacle(SpectacleView spectacle)
        {
            Client currentUser = OnlineUsers.GetSessionUser().ToUser();
            spectacle.IdDistributeur = currentUser.idClient;
            ViewBag.Categories = DB.Categories;
            ViewBag.testCat = new SelectList(DB.Categories, "idCategories", "Description");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
                DB.AddSpectacle(spectacle);
            else
                return View(spectacle);
            return RedirectToAction("Spectacles");
        }`

the variable spectacle has a idCategorie that should be sent an id from the select, but the value is always 0. I'm trying to make it send the right value from the select
[image: Categories]

My guess is that I'm making an obvious mistake, but i just can't seem to grasp it.

Edited: This is my part of my SpecacleView:

```
    public int idSpectacle { get; set; }

    public String ImageId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Nom du Spectacle")]
    public string nomSpectacle { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Description")]
    public string description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Categories")]
    public int idCategories { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Prix de base")]
    public decimal prix_de_base { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Nom de l'artiste")]
    public string nomArtiste { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Requis")]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    public string PictureImageData { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private ImageGUIDReference PictureReference { get; set; }
    public int IdDistributeur { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the SpectacleView class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a post of a form the data is sent as a key-value pairs where the key is the name attribute of the element and the value is the value that the user provided, or selected. Then, when the controller receives a post data, it maps the key of the data received to a property with the same name in the view model.

So in your case, the name of the select that you are using is `Categorie` and in the view model you expect the key for it to be `idCategorie`. You should either change the Name attribute in the `<select>` to `idCategorie` or change in the property name in the viewmodel to `Categorie`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that the controller needed the same names for it to work.